# Create Azure Data Factory v2 withot AD app registration

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there any way to create Azure Data Factory v2 client without create AD app in azure?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could do this with SDK or restful API

Data factory service identity is generated as follows:

1. When creating data factory through Azure portal or PowerShell,
   service identity will always be created automatically since ADF V2
   public preview.
2. When creating data factory through SDK, service
   identity **will be created only** if you specify "Identity = new
   FactoryIdentity()" in the factory object for creation. See example
   in .NET quickstart - create data factory.
3. When creating data factory through REST API, service identity **will be created only** if you specify "identity" section in request body. See example in REST quickstart - create data factory.

Please reference [this doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity)

Comment: thanks, but for this step DataFactoryManagementClient should be already created. I found in quick start doc only option how they create it with registered AD app...

Comment: As my understanding, if you don’t specify it, then it won’t be created, right?

Comment: yes, in examples AD app used to generate token credentians. That credentials are passed into DataFactoryManagementClient constructor. i'm wondering if there's other way to create TokenCredentials object, without AD app

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood you question. I thought you are asking how to create a data factory without generate a data factory application id.